# How to use tenseal on cuda

Tags: python

I am trying to use tenseal for neural network under homomorphic encryption, but the ckksvector in tenseal cannot be carried with cuda. Is there any solution that can use cuda for tenseal library

I wanted to find a solution that would support computationsfor homomorphic encryption using the tenseal library on cuda.